# Problem in model fit () in Keras R Package for a simple DNN

Tags: r, keras, deep-learning

I've been trying to fit a simple model for a house price prediction in the following model:
[image: Code]

Everything runs fine till the `fit` part, where I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

I've tried installing reticulate and RTools manually, using online notebooks like Kaggle and could not figure out how to implement this. Can somebody help me please. Thanks in advance!

I've tried using the library KerasR as well but couldn't get it running too, but for other reasons:  invalid 'dimnames' given for data set, but this is something for another post

Comment: Hi. It's customery to include the text and error message as text when possible, rather than screenshots. In the screenshots, you are defining a simple sequential model that takes a single input, but you are passing in a data frame to `fit()`. You need to convert your data frame to a matrix first.

Comment: Hi! I'm sorry! This was my first post here and Stack didn't let me comment as text, it kept saying that my post was mainly code (and I couldn't post). Very sorry! going to try harder next time! In regards to refraiming the imput as a matrix, i've already tried this, and it gives the following error: "Matrix type cannot be converted to python (only integer, numeric, complex, logical, and character matrixes can be converted" (I've tried train_selected = matrix(train_selected) and train_selected = as.matrix(train_selected). Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: what is the type of matrix you have? `str(matrix)` should tell you what you need. My guess is that you are unintentionally creating an R list, and want to be making an R numeric matrix.

Comment: Hi, kalinowski. I've already tried to convert the list into a matrix using the 'matrix ()', function, but it outputs the following error:  "Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  Matrix type cannot be converted to python (only integer, numeric, complex, logical, and character matrixes can be converted". The error says it is already on a matrix type, but when i run the "str" function, it still tells me that it's a list. (on the environment section of RStudio it describes the variable as a large matrix, though). Any thoughts? Thanks for the answer!